# How do you create Revision Table in Arcmap for OSM contribution?

Tags: arcmap, openstreetmap, cartography

I have created the following detailed file for upload to OSM in ArcMap but don't know about creating a OSM Revision Table to be able to put the data into OSM.

At 1:10,000
[image]

At 1:1000
[image]

The tool
[image]

What do I do? I searched but found nothing about how to create the revision file.

http://esriosmeditor.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Tools&referringTitle=Documentation...mentions

> The second parameter is the local revision table storing the changeset
>   information that is submitted to the OSM server. This table also
>   stores the upload status, i.e. if the data upload was successful or if
>   the upload resulted in conflicts. The conflict editor will use the
>   same table to guide you through the conflict resolution. The table
>   name has the schema of osmrevision where  is the name of
>   the feature dataset where the OSM data resides.

but doesn't mention what fields this table needs, the format etc.

When I try the OSM Download Tool I get
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The processes involved got to complex to run for the project so in the end I used the Global Mapper "export to web" option which creates tiles at the given resolution and the associated html code to put into a web page. These tiles then seamlessly blend into OSM and GE/GM plus many other formats.

Additionally the data which was basically a site plan was not really appropriate for OSM contribution as it wasn't a permanent set up applicable for the general public.

Thank you for your responses which I will use for other projects.

Answer (score 2):

There may be other ways to prepare OpenStreetMap data for upload but if you are using ArcGIS Editor for OpenStreetMap 2.1 Beta (goes with ArcGIS 10.1) then I would recommend following the workflow in the [Documentation](http://esriosmeditor.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Download%20Data%20from%20OSM&referringTitle=Documentation).  I did that and started by using the Download, Extract, and Symbolize OSM Data tool/model, then after editing in ArcMap, the OSM Revision Table was sitting in the file geodatabase I had used for editing.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I get a tool not licenced error when I try the download tool as the first step of the instructions. I don't see any info on how to register the tool on the site.

Comment: I did sign up to the 2.1 Beta but I don't think there was any license unlocking as a result.  I think the only license it should check for is an ArcGIS for Desktop 10.1.  There is an ArcGIS Editor for OSM forum you may be able to access via http://esriosmeditor.codeplex.com/ too.

Comment: Just wanted to double-check that if you are using 10.0 you need 2.0, but if like me you are using 10.1 you need 2.1 Beta at the moment.

Comment: I have 10.1 and using 2.1 Beta

Comment: Thanks. I still get the 000816 error -I have cross-posted in http://esriosmeditor.codeplex.com/discussions/394714

Answer (score 2):

Some clarifications - yes, the revision table is automatically generated when you use the ArcGIS Editor for OSM tools to download data from OSM into a geodatabase, or if you use the Load OSM File tool in that same toolbox to load an .osm file into a geodatabase. As pointed out earlier in the thread, it will be located in the same geodatabase in which your generated feature dataset resides. You should not have to edit the revision table manually at all - do not add columns, or change values. The revision table will automatically be populated when you edit the OSM feature dataset, tracking your edits. Then, those edits are uploaded through the revision table when you use the Upload OSM Data tool. This has been clarified in the ArcGIS Editor for OSM documentation as a result of this thread.

Also - to use the latest version of ArcGIS Editor for OSM, you must first uninstall the current version if you have it installed.

You do not need a special license or specific level of ArcGIS license to use the ArcGIS Editor for OSM - however, ArcGIS for Desktop itself needs to be running with a valid license.

Regarding what versions of ArcGIS Editor for OSM to use - for ArcGIS 10, yes use ArcGIS Editor for OSM 2.0.  For ArcGIS 10.1, use the current beta version ArcGIS Editor for OSM 2.1 Beta.

Feel free to respond on the ArcGIS Editor for OSM forum as well - http://esriosmeditor.codeplex.com/discussions.

Comment: Thanks. I got the following from the OSM Forum - From: temge

I think you found yourself in the unfortunate situation between betas releases that were misconfigured. The OSM tools should always be licensed and always work after the install. However....there was an unfortunate chain of events where my first attempt of making the toolbox work in 10.0 and 10.1 failed miserably. All this got fixed last night and should be working again with the next beta.
[continued...]

Comment: [...continued] Unless you are explicitly attempting to use the new networking tool I would suggest to stick with the 2.0 release until the next beta is pushed -- which at that point should also be feature complete.

- Thomas

Answer (score 1):

**OSM Revison table** is located in

C:\Users\[username]\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\OSM2_osm_revision.gdb table

[image]

An Example is here:

Source:
http://esriosmeditor.codeplex.com/discussions/353838

There is a process for conflicts that takes place after this.
but you can check your own changeset is upload by addyour changeset number to the url.

http://www.openstreetmap.org/browse/changeset/id_number (example:11483204)

Comment: Thanks. My issue is that the OSM toolset doesn't run. I have cross posted in http://esriosmeditor.codeplex.com/discussions/394714.